# Python script has execution error first time through on a JoinField, but not the second time

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, error-000732

I have some Python code that takes a shapefile, creates its centroids via FeatureToPoint, joins an auxillary field from the shapefile to the centroid via JoinField, and then goes on to do some more work with the centroids.

The relevant code is:

```
centroids = arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(shapefile, "centroids", "CENTROID")
arcpy.JoinField_management(centroids, "ORIG_FID", shapefile, "FID", "EXTRA_FIELD")
```

When I execute this script the first time, I get an error for the JoinField line:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset centroids does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (JoinField).
```

However, checking for the generated centroids shows that it has been created and exists on disk.

When I then execute the script a second time around there is no error and the script proceeds as normal.

While I'm glad to continue executing it twice as far as getting results I need, I'd really like to debug this and figure out why it fails the first time through.

**Update**

I believe I am running into problems because of how I try to assign the results of FeatureToPoint to the variable `centroids` and then use `centroids` in the rest of the code. I added some sanity checks to the above snippet like so:

```
print(shapefile)
centroids = arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(shapefile, "centroids", "CENTROID")
print(centroids)
arcpy.JoinField_management(centroids, "ORIG_FID", shapefile, "FID", "EXTRA_FIELD")
```

The first time through it reads (before failing on the JoinField of course):

```
D:/temp/boundary.shp
centroids
```

The second time through it reads (and continues on with rest of the script):

```
D:/temp/boundary.shp
D:/temp/centroids.shp
```

Comment: Try MakeFeatureLayer_management on `centroids` and pass that into JoinField instead. I believe join field expects feature layers or table views, not feature classes or tables. Also, are you setting your `arcpy.env.workspace`?

Comment: `arcpy.env.workspace` is set, in the above example to `D:/temp/`. Should I not be referring to a feature class by a variable and instead always by a path?

Comment: I guess the moral of this story is to not rely on the return values for geoprocessing functions. Seems like a bug.

Comment: What's frustrating is often I want to know *why* this ends up working the way it does but because of ESRI/ARC quirkiness or lack of documentation, I'll probably be spinning my wheels unless someone can shed some light.

Comment: There's some documentation about "Getting results from a tool" at http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000n000000 That section and the whole document of a few pages are worth reading to help understand the difference between a tool's Output and its Result object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on the right track. I just tried something like below with shapefiles, and it all worked just fine. FeatureToPoint isn't supposed to *return* anything, it creates your centroid FC that you specify, centroids.shp in my case below.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\where ever shapes live"
arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management("shapefile.shp", "centroids.shp", "CENTROID")
arcpy.JoinField_management("centroids.shp", "ORIG_FID", "shapefile.shp", "FID", "EXTRA_FIELD"
```

Comment: So perhaps I shouldn't worry about inconsistency in its return value if I'm not even supposed to be using it?

Answer (score 1):

Try arcpy.JoinField_management("centroids", "ORIG_FID", shapefile, "FID", "EXTRA_FIELD")